# Google apps script onedit even not grabbing column title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-6";
  var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();//Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  var updateColName = sheet.getRange( 1, editColumn).getValue ();
  var timeStampColName = "null";

  if (updateColName == "PACK STARTED BY") {timeStampColName = "Pack Start";}

if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Above is the code I am running in my sheet. Now This on edit event is supposed to grab the column title from the currently active cell. then using if statements should be putting a static value into the timestamp column name so I can put timestamps in my sheet. I am having a really hard time debugging this since I don't know how to debug on edit in the google scripting screen. So I can't tell what is not right about the code. Right now it does nothing.

Comment: Going through the code provided is confusing. (e.g. `editColumn` was is being used in line 6, but was only declared in line 8 and `timeStampColName` used, but not value provided upon declaration). Could you format the code accordingly, and see if that makes any changes.

Comment: I made the changes. I was using static references but now I need to grab the column title of the cell I am editing to generate the timestamp in the proper cell. So I put the if statement in there to grab the title of the cell I am editing, Then trying to use the if statement to declare the timestampcolname. Then running the rest of the script as it ran before.

Comment: The results are the same so far the time stamp is not being applied.